# How to connect Android TreeView library to my project?

Tags: android, android-studio

This is a pretty newbie question.

I found a **[Polidea TreeView Library](https://github.com/Polidea/tree-view-list-android)** for Android.

But how do I use it for my project in Android Studio?

I've tried several things - adding the .jar files directly, importing as Project/Module, setting the dependencies in Gradle. But none of this worked.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually it turned out, that the best way of connecting this library - just copy src. It's easier, than messing up with Gradle.

In Eclipse everything works fine, by the way.